# Looking for old comedy movie set in medieval times

Tags: story-identification, movie, medieval

Its an old movie I saw as a kid. It's a comedy set in a medieval court. The main character is sort of helpless. I remember when he has to fight in a joust and his armor gets magnetized by a lightning bolt. He also gets hypnotized into being a great fencer at the end of the movie. It's shot a lot like a play and has a lot of physical humor.

Comment: Is this really sci-fi / fantasy within the guidelines of the site ?

Comment: @Stan It sounds like fantasy. The suit of armour becoming magnetised by a lightning strike would certainly push it into that category...

Comment: @Richard I've seen the movie a number of times. I wouldn't classify it as fantasy as used by this site, certainly not based on that one single item.  Was a great film (Kaye was a great comedian) but think this one really should be moved to a more appropriate exchange site.

Comment: http://youtu.be/6zIWcCvQNqQ?t=1m15s - It's physical comedy f'sho, but it's still fantastical

Comment: We'll just have to disagree on this one.  Fantastical is a bit different than fantasy.  Something can be fantastical because it's far-fetched and hard to believe but that doesn't necessarily give it a basis in fantasy.  Like I said, just think it should be migrated that's all.

Comment: It also had a band of dwarves, played by midgets.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sound like [*The Court Jester*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049096/) to me - 1950's musical-comedy film set in medieval England where a hapless carnival performer ([Danny Kaye](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001414/?ref_=tt_cl_t1)) masquerades as the legendary king of jesters, Giacomo, as part of a plot against evil rulers ([Basil Rathbone](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001651/?ref_=tt_cl_t3) & Cecil Parker) who have overthrown the rightful king.

[image: Image montage of The Court Jester]

After the Princess ([Angela Lansbury](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001450/?ref_=tt_cl_t4)) falls for him, Kaye is hypnotized by the court sorceress into believing he is also a master assassin and swordsman. Some highlights of this Robin Hood/Scaramouche spoof include a wonderful sword fight with Rathbone in which Kaye constantly switches identities and the legendary "chalice from the palace/vessel with pestle" confusion.

[image: Movie poster for The Court Jester]

For the full plot check out the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Court_Jester) or just watch the movie again, it's hilarious!

Comment: There's also a mention of the armour here; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LightningCanDoAnything

Answer (score 2):

It was known as *[The Spaceman and King Arthur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidentified_Flying_Oddball)* in the UK and *Unidentified Flying Oddball* elsewhere. It starred Jim Dale and was made in 1979. It's a remake of *A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court* with a NASA employee being the man sent to the past.

His ship uses magnetic fields to travel faster than the speed of light and, at one point in the film, he uses that mechanism to stick several armored troops to the outside of his ship.

Comment: Can you add some details to show how this matches the question?

Comment: I don't think this is the right *answer*, but it is a plausible one with the whole magnetism thing. No hypnotism, though.